# Quip Live App authentication with the Quip default Salesforce org

Tags: quip, liveapps

I have a Quip instance linked to a Salesforce org. I'm trying to create a Live App that authenticates against that Salesforce org and fetches some data, similar to the [Salesforce record example Quip live app](https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/tree/master/examples/salesforce-record)

However, when I try to authenticate with`quip.apps.auth('salesforce')`, it can't find the Salesforce org that I already linked to my Quip instance. See [example from Quip example live apps repo](https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/blob/master/examples/salesforce-record/src/root.jsx#L59).

Is there a way to authenticate against the linked Salesforce org in a Quip live app?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a connected App in Salesforce, then create an oauth auth config on the quip dev console using the client and secret you generated from the org and then use the Redirect URL generated by quip the Quip console as the callback url in your Salesforce connected app.